# GWT RequestFactory RequestContext.append what guarantees on order of firing receivers?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

If I have two or more request contexts (appended) each with one or more service method requests is there any guarantee on the order the receivers are fired?

The code seems to fire service method receivers in the order they were called and then the requestcontext (void) receiver. Is that just current behaviour and subject to change?

Cheers

Sam

Answer (score 1):

The order receivers are called is guaranteed to be the order methods have been called on the `RequestContext`s; this is by-design.
The same is true for the order methods are called on the server-side.

Comment: Many thanks Thomas, worth trying to submit a patch to add javadoc comment to this effect?